# Javascript Function, returning a function clarification

Tags: javascript

I have JS code to show the messages on focus of each element. See the snippet.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="help">Helpful notes will appear here</p>
        <p>E-mail: <input type="text" id="email" name="email"></p>
        <p>Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name"></p>
        <p>Age: <input type="text" id="age" name="age"></p>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        function showHelp(help) {
            var myFunc = function () {
                document.getElementById('help').innerHTML = help;
            }
            return myFunc;
        }
        function setupHelp() {
            var helpText = [
                {'id': 'age', 'help': 'Your age (you must be over 16)'},
                {'id': 'email', 'help': 'Your e-mail address'},
                {'id': 'name', 'help': 'Your full name'}
            ];
            for (var i = 0; i < helpText.length; i++) {
                var item = helpText[i];
                document.getElementById(item.id).onfocus = showHelp(item.help);

            }
        }
        setupHelp();
    </script>
</html>
```

When focus is on each input element, correct messages are shown and it is working as expected. But when I changed the code to

```
document.getElementById(item.id).onfocus = function () {
 return showHelp(item.help);
}
```

Then the messages are not showing. What is the difference between two?

Comment: `document.getElementById(item.id).onfocus = function () { return showHelp(item.help); }()` Or ``document.getElementById(item.id).onfocus = function () { return showHelp(item.help)(); }``

Comment: The second example will return `myFunc` without invoking it, so when the  `onfocus` event is triggert it will return `myFunc`, whereas in the the first example the `onfocus` is set to `myFunc`, which will be called, when an `onfocus` event occurs. Hope that makes sense. ;)

Comment: @dfsq It is clear now.

Comment: @DavidDomain Make sense (Y)

Comment: @DavidDomain  It would be great if you can clarify this. Why `myFunc` is not automatically invoked when `onfocus` event is triggered in second example?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your last question in comment, the second example you have onfocus is assigned a function, that returns a function inturn. The onfocus event generated by your element triggers the function invocation. The function you have provided to onfocus event is just a handler. No action is taken on the object or function you return.
Here is a simple example to make your understanding better.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" >
      function showHelp() {
          console.log('showHelp');
      }
      document.getElementById('email').onfocus = function () {
       console.log('onfocus');
       return showHelp();
     }
  </script>
</html>
```

When you run the above code, you will only see `onfocus` printed on console but never the log inside `showHelp()` function.